# If a div exists, move on to the next item

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have a for loop going through a list of searches. I want to check to see if the search throws an error. I want to accomplish this by determining if a specific class exists. If the error class does exist, I want the for loop to move to the next item. Here is the code:

```
for each in open('temp.txt'):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ip)
    alert = soup.find("div", class_="alert alert-danger")
    if alert is not None:
       i = soup.findAll("span", class_="name")
       for x in i:
          *do something*
    else:
       *move to the next "each" in the for loop within temp.txt*
```

I have tried things like "continue" or "next" but with no success. If I could get some guidance I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `else` part at all, if `alert is None`, the loop would continue to the next item:

```
for each in open('temp.txt'):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ip)
    alert = soup.find("div", class_="alert alert-danger")
    if alert is not None:
       i = soup.findAll("span", class_="name")
       for x in i:
          *do something*
```